# Taking the integral of a rational function

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve $$\int \frac{x^2}{(16-x^2)^{3/2}}\,dx$$
But I'm seriously stuck, I've been working at this problem for a couple days now. I change it into the form

$$\int \frac{x^2}{8(4-x^2)^{3/2}}\,dx$$

then I substitute $x = 2\sin(u)$

$$\int \frac{(2\sin(u))^2}{8(4( 1 - \sin(u)^2)^{3/2}}\,dx$$

I use the identity $\cos^2 u = 1- \sin^2u$

$$\int \frac{(2\sin(u))^2}{64(( \cos^2(u))^{3/2}}\,dx$$

and simplify

$$\int \frac{4\sin^2(u)}{64( \cos(u)^3}\,dx$$

I know that $dx = du/\cos(u)$

$$\frac{1}{16}\int \frac{\sin^2(u)}{ \cos(u)^4}\,du$$

I go along this path, and I end up getting stuck. If I'm on the right track, knowing such is sufficient for me, but if I have made a mistake somewhere, please let me know! Thank you for the help, these types of problems have really been difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int \frac{x^2}{(16-x^2)^{\frac 32}}dx\\
x = 4\sin u, dx = 4\cos u\ du\\
\displaystyle\int \frac{64\sin^2u\cos u }{64\cos^3 u}du\\
\displaystyle\int \tan^2 u\ du\\
\displaystyle\int \sec^2 u -1\ du\\
\tan u  - u\\
\frac {x}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} - \arcsin \frac {x}{4}
$

Comment: First, this is NOT a "rational function".  More importantly, ${16- x^2}^{3/2}$ is not equal to $8(4- x^2)^{3/2}$1

Comment: @user247327 is that comment directed at me or the OP?

Answer (score 1):

With $x=4\sin u$ then $dx=4\cos u\,du$ and then
$$\int \frac{16\sin^2u}{64\cos^3u}4\cos udu= \int\tan^2u\,du=\int1+\tan^2u-1\,du=(\tan u-u)+C$$
with $u=\arcsin\dfrac{x}{4}$ find the result.